# How do I realize how much I earn when the user clicks on an advertisement? Admob

Tags: java, android, admob, native, ads

I want to know how much I earn when a user in my application clicks on a CPC. I'm using Admob.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about ad rates for advertising networks, not programming.

Comment: It's not for only advertising networks...